# CodeMirror: ad-hoc syntax highlighting

Tags: dsl, codemirror

Can I use CodeMirror in more ad-hoc mode, where the "grammar", or, rather, the highlighting, emerges as the user types the code?

Assume, for example, that I would like to highlight similarities between sentences. Then, assume that the user types:

```
this is a sentence
this is another sentence
```

Assume, further, that the user then puts the cursor on one of the sentences. I'd like all the common subsequences to be highlighted between the two sentences, like so:

```
|this is| a |sentence|
|this is| another |sentence|
```

Is CodeMirror the right answer for these kind of ad-hoc syntax highlighting tasks, or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create your dynamic mode at run-time, you can use `setOption` to update the mode for a running editor. Alternatively, use `markText` to do the highlighting programmatically.